# Translate Oracle query into pandas dataframe handling

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, oracle

I have the below dataframe:

| PARAM1 | PARAM2 | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | TUE, WED |
| A | Y | NO |
| B | X | MON, WED |
| B | Y | YES |

I would like a pythonic way of obtaining the distinct values of param1 that satisfy EITHER of these conditions:

1. Their corresponding param2 = 'X' contains the string 'MON'
2. Their corresponding param2 = 'Y' is equal to 'YES'.

In the example above, the output would be just B, because.

| PARAM1 | PARAM2 | VALUE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | TUE, WED | X parameter does not contain 'MON', so does not count for A. |
| A | Y | NO | Y parameter is not equal to 'YES', so does not count for A. |
| B | X | MON, WED | X parameter contains 'MON', so it counts for B. |
| B | Y | YES | Y parameter is equal to 'YES', so it counts for B. |

Since A has not met either of the criteria for param2 X and Y, it's not in the output. B has fulfilled both (would have been enough with just one), so it's in the output.

In Oracle I would do it this way, but not sure how to proceed in python:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    param1
FROM
    (
        -- Fetch the X entries having a 'MON' in value
        SELECT
            param1
        FROM
            aux
        WHERE
            param2 = 'X'
            AND REGEXP_LIKE ( value,
                              'MON' )
        UNION ALL
        -- Fetch the Y entries having value equal to 'YES'
        SELECT
            param1
        FROM
            aux
        WHERE
            param2 = 'Y'
            AND param3 = 'YES'
    );
```

Comment: In Oracle it can be done by `OR` of two conditions with a single table scan: `(param2 = 'X' and value like '%MON%') or (param2 = 'Y' and value = 'YES')`. I hope the same can be done in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we form a boolean mask based on the condition, then select the corresponding rows from the dataframe:

```
cond = ((df['PARAM2'] == 'X') & df['VALUE'].str.contains('MON')) | \
       ((df['PARAM2'] == 'Y') & df['VALUE'].str.contains('YES'))
df = df[cond]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  PARAM1 PARAM2     VALUE
2      B      X  MON, WED
3      B      Y       YES
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should take the unique to achieve the output? df['PARAM1'].unique()?

Comment: I think you can use `.drop_duplicates(keep='first')`

Comment: I would like just the values from PARAM1, in a list.

Comment: In this case, yes, `print(df['PARAM1'].unique().tolist())`